# PhpDoc create warnings because it can't find library class

Tags: php, phpdoc

When lauching phpdocumentor on a project, it creates warnings like that in the "Post-parsing" :

```
Class ... not found
```

These are all the library classes I use, but I don't want a documentation on that. And phpdoc can't find them.

Is there a way to suppress those warnings ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to suppress the warnings...

An extreme workaround, though, would be to have a single dummy file that contains empty class declarations for all the "missing" classes, where each class's docblock uses the @ignore tag to prevent it from being documented... it still gets parsed, so no more warning.

Comment: I'm sad, now it messes the phpUnderControl stats, thanks for the answer.